# Change the description for username field in user registration

Tags: 7, forms, users

I would like to disable the spaces in the usernames. For that I installed a rules module and i applied a rule. Everything is fine but now the label is still saying : `"Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods, hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores."`

How can i change that label ? I looked everywhere and i didn't find a thing.

I am new to drupal.
I use drupal 7.

Thanks in advance for you responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another couple of options using string translation techniques:

1. Contrib module: [String Overrides](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides)
2. `settings.php` snippet insert

The string overrides module lets you do the string translation via the UI.
Otherwise, you can set the override in settings.php - the search string needs to match exactly.

```
/**
 * String overrides:
 *
 * To override specific strings on your site with or without enabling locale
 * module, add an entry to this list. This functionality allows you to change
 * a small number of your site's default English language interface strings.
 */
$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
  'Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods, hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores.' => 'Spaces and punctuation are not allowed except for periods, hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores.',
);
```

Comment: The StringOverrides module is awsome. I used it and everything is fine now. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The text is in user_account_form function https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_account_form/7

To change it, you can implement a hook_form_alter. I believe the text appears on two forms, 'user_register_form' and 'user_profile_form'. Create a module, put this in it (change mymodule to your module name).

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_register_form' || $form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    $form['account']['name']['#description'] = t('This will be the new text Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods, hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores.');
  }
}
```

Comment: Note,  this approach will work but no need to return $form in hook_form_alter as the $form variable is passed by reference .

Comment: I trust that this is another solution but i did not changed code in drupal since i use drupal, so i tried the StringOverrides module which did the job. Thanks a lot for your answer too.